# Illegal Configurations Xcode 6.4

Tags: xcode

What are illegal configurations and how do I fix them?

I have 3:

> Launch screens may not use instances of IBUIExitPlace Holder.
>
> Launch screens may only have one top level object, which must be a UIView or a kind of UIViewController.
>
> Launch screens may not use instances of IBUIStoryboardEntryPointIndicator.

I'm converting my Swift 2 code to Swift 1.2 so I can upload my app to the app store.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with Swift. Your launch screen has the issues mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just stomped with the exact same issue.

I think you can reproduce the issue with the following steps:

- Create a Launch Screen.storyboard using Xcode 7 beta 5
- Open Xcode 6.4 and try to build the project, it should fail.

What I did to fix this was to delete the Launch Screen.storyboard created on XCode 7b5 and create a new one on XCode 6.4.

Please let me know if you try this solution!

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue. This issue is generally caused because of creating a Storyboard using XCode 7 and using the same Storyboard file in Xcode 6.  Follow the below steps to solve the issue.

1. Delete the LaunchScreen storyboard created by Xcode 7.
2. Create a new LaunchScreen storyboard using Xcode 6.
3. Clean and Build.